# Will Azure Data Lake Analytics support ADLS Gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

We have a number of projects based on ADLA+ADLS Gen1 and we recently noticed that prices for Gen1 are not available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/data-lake/) any more. Also ADLA isn't listed in the Gen1->Gen2 [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json).

Googling brought no relief, so seeking for advise and insights re:

- Will ADLA support ADLS Gen2?
- Will ADLS Gen1 will be discontinued?
- Will ADLA be discontinued?

Comment: Hello, if the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.As of now, ADLA does not support ADLS Gen2, there is already a user voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/36445702-add-support-for-adls-gen2-to-adla). You can upvote for it.

2.For ADLS Gen1 will be discounted or not, there is a [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27144#issuecomment-472715065) about this as following:

**As of now there are no plans to retire ADLS gen 1. However it's recommended to migrate to Gen2 as most of the latest features and improvements will be rolled out to Gen2.**

3.Based on 1, if Microsoft supports 1 as per the user voice, then ADLA will be not retired. But not very sure.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 will be retired on Feb 29, 2024. MS are not investing in ADLA.

Customers were recommended   migrate Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and  ADLA to an alternate framework such as Azure HDInsight, Azure Synapse Analytics or Azure Databricks.